# S Galaxy mini 2 rebooting every 12 seconds... I'd like at least to save some data!

Tags: boot-loop, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-mini

A pair of months ago I bought my first smartphone, so I am quite the noob. Suddently last week it decided to restart every 12-13 seconds (literally), as long as I don't remove the battery, and I can't find a solution on the internet. Of course I could give it to the support, but they warned me that by this way I'll lose all my data, while I'd like to save at least some. On the internet I found a couple of people with my same problem and no answer (if we exclude the "I left it in its frenzy the whole night, when I woke it was resolved", which in my case mysteriously didn't work) can you help me?

DETAILS - Samsung Galaxy mini 2 GT-S6500, no SD

THE INCIDENT - I was playing a game when it freezed (no answer from any button short of the 8 seconds forced shut down), as it had already happened, so I pressed the "off" button and started waiting, since it usually worked; I fell asleep, and when I woke up the screen was on and black. When I restarted it manually it started the evil madness. I had not installed any new app, or so I remember.

FAILED TREATMENTS
- Can't enter recovery mode by holding Volume up (+), Volume down (-) and Home button and then power on the phone. Nor does any combination of Volume, Power and Home work in any way...

Comment: It's particularly strange that you can't get into Recovery or Download mode. I did some googling and found: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbLcij05jH8 . So it's really a thing. The description of that youtube link suggests that it was a hardware failure, that the owner's father repaired with a soldering iron. That's pretty intense! If you can't get into recovery mode, can't boot normally, and can't connect to USB... I think you might be out of luck. Anyone else have ideas?

Comment: Uh, this hardcore solution looks way out of my possibilities... plus I'd prefer not to risk damaging the hardware since I would lose free support...
I was wondering... isn't there any program capable of making my pc read the smartphone memory even if it is off, so that I can at least save my data?

Anyway, thanks, at least I have some idea of the source of the problem!

Comment: Like I said before: If you can't get into recovery mode, can't boot normally, and can't connect to USB... I don't think so. Somebody else might have better news for you, though!

Comment: Have you tried a USB jig? That will get you into download mode. Maybe then you can flash a better recovery If it's still rebooting in recovery/download, you probably have a serious hardware issue and data recovery is going to be unlikely.